# Can't start Chef-server

Tags: chef-infra

Things I did, step by step:

1. `wget https://packages.chef.io/stable/ubuntu/14.04/chef-server-core_12.8.0-1_amd64.deb`
2. `wget https://packages.chef.io/stable/ubuntu/12.04/chefdk_0.17.17-1_amd64.deb`
3. `sudo dpkg -i chef*`
4. Wait for them to install
5. And `sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure` gives me

> /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.5.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:479:in `remove_old_node_state`: undefined method `success?` for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
>       from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.5.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:495:in `run_chef`
>       from /opt/opscode/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/chef-server-ctl:222:in `reconfigure`
>       from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.5.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:736:in `run`
>       from /opt/opscode/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/chef-server-ctl:237:in `<main>`

My /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb:

> server_name = "IP.ADD.RES.123"
>   api_fqdn server_name 
> bookshelf['vip'] =
>   server_name 
> nginx['url'] = "http://#{server_name}"
>   nginx['server_name'] = server_name

(same error even if I leave this empty, or set server_name to 'localhost', 'crti-test-vps' or whatever)

Server is hosted at DigitalOcean and doesn't have a domain name yet.

`uname -a`:

`Linux crti-test-vps 4.4.0-28-generic #47~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 16:30:35 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Use a real fqdn, a lot of things won't work with an IP address as `server_name`. (And so if your system can't resolve properly it's own host name, this will fail also)

Comment: I tried localhost, hostname --fdqn, same error. It seems like call to `system()` in omnibus-ctl.rb just return nil or something.

Comment: Does a `dig fqdn`properly resolve to something ? Are you running `chef-server-ctl` as root ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better on Chef mailing list at http://discourse.chef.io

Comment: Well after re reading your Q, run `sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure` it has to be run as root, as you're using sudo for the package install I bet you're not using it for the chef-server-ctl call, and obvisouly it fails writing at some places on the system.

Comment: No, I ran at with sudo ofc... I'll edit the Q.

Comment: Without a complete log the the chef-server-ctl reconfigure, it's impossible to guess what's going wrong with your install. Again I'm pretty sure SO is not the place for this kind of debug.

Comment: `remove_old_node_state` is just doing a `rm -rf /opt/opscode/embeded/nodes/` it calls `system ` for that. if it returns `nil`, it means `rm`  did fail...

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Things I made that helped me to resolve the issue:

1. Turned off nginx `sudo service nginx stop` - the error still persisted
2. Turned off apache2 `sudo service apache2 stop` - the error was gone but `sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure` was returning other errors or no output at all (I felt it was random)
3. Rebooted the server

After rebooting I successfully reconfigured chef. I think the problem may be connected with the amount of free RAM. I had small amount of free RAM before rebooting but I don't remember how much.